# Can Alpine3D's code be compiled following their instructions?

Tags: visual-studio, compile, dll, mingw, cmake

I have been attempting to run [Alpine3d](https://models.slf.ch/p/alpine3d/) for a personal project to model wind-drifted snow. This software uses 3 main libraries of code (each of which are open source projects of the SLF): MeteoIO, Snowpack, and Alpine3d. I have primarily tried (and failed) to run this program in 3 ways:

1. Install using a normal .exe installer on Windows 10
2. Compile from source code
3. Run the program on linux

Below I've included the details of my attempts at getting the first two methods to work. My hope is that someone who knows how to compile code will be kind enough to test if they get the same result.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

---

**1) Installed Alpine3d normally on Windows 10** - Downloaded only the [Alpine3d Windows installer](https://models.slf.ch/p/alpine3d/downloads/281/). The program has a successful install and is meant to be run from the command line. In the command line I attempt to validate the install by either using a path variable or going to the install folder and calling the help menu:

```
alpine3d.exe -help
```

I receive the errors (2):

> System Error - "The code execution cannot  proceed because
>   libsnowpack.dll was not found. Reinstalling the  program may fix this
>   problem."
>
> System Error - "The code execution cannot proceed because 
>   alpine3d.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this 
>   problem."

My hunch is that the installer couldn't find libsnowpack.dll on my computer and couldn't product the subsequent alpine3d.dll. libsnowpack.dll is not produced from the install of the Snowpack software. It seems very difficult to repair the installer so I set off on attempt #2.

**2) Attempted to compile it from source code** - [Instructions are provided](https://models.slf.ch/p/meteoio/page/Compiling-MeteoIO/)  specifying to use CMake and either Visual Studio, MinGW, or Code::Blocks to compile the code.

MinGW appears in the gui to successfully configure and generate the compiler code but when I run mingw32-make on this folder I get the error

> "The code execution cannot proceed because libwinpthread-1.dll was not
>   found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

For the Code:blocks compiler, the configuration fails and asks for the location of libsnowpack.dll.a. This file doesn't exist, making me think that Snowpack needs to be compiled from source code as well in order to produce a .dll.a

When I try to compile [Snowpack from its source code](https://models.slf.ch/p/snowpack/downloads/330/) with Visual Studio (15 2017) as the compiler, CMake does not automatically find MeteoIO. It is looking for a 'Meteoio_Inlcude_Dir' and 'Meteoio_Library'. The note in CMake says for the library it is looking for something like a .lib file. I have investigated replacing the .lib with the .dll with no luck. It seems the .lib needs to be generated from a successful compile of the MeteoIO source code.

When I try to compile MeteoIO from source code (with VS), CMake successfully generates the .sln file without any additional configuration. When I try to build the .sln with the local debugger it successfully builds the .lib, .dll, and a .exp file. The .lib is 2,840 kb.

When I try to compile (VS) Snowpack with this .lib file, it raises the issue of where the 'Meteo_Include_Dir' is. An 'Include' folder did not come with the source code. If it was supposed to be created in the build process, I cannot find it. I did find an 'Include' folder in the directory structure that was built by the [.exe setup install](https://models.slf.ch/p/meteoio/downloads/321/) for MeteoIO.  I have also tried copying the MeteoIO folder and pasting it into a newly created 'include' folder at the same level as the 'doc' and 'tools' folders. Using the 'include' folder downloaded with Windows installer, the (4) builds run successfully and only a libsnowpack.lib file (2,984 kb) is produced successfully (in the source code folder), though not where I'd expect.

I have tried to use this libsnowpack.lib file to generate the alpine3d.dll file I need. However, I cannot hack my way around a missing 'include' folder for Snowpack because the Windows installer doesn't create it. The libsnowpack.dll, specified in the original error, for Alpine3d was not produced from compiling Snowpack.

Am I doing something wrong in the build process? Should the compiler be producing more than just the .lib file? Has anyone had better luck with a compiler that they know works? I don't know that I've successfully compiled any code yet.

Thanks again if you've read this far,

Brian

Note: Installing all 3 pieces of software sequentially with the installer doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The installer for Alpine3D was actually broken (missing Snowpack), it has been removed from the downloads. This means that you must recompile from source until a new package is made.

Please really follow the instructions provided on the web site. You can not skip steps, otherwise it will not work. I also recommend against VC++ since recent versions have problems with Snowpack. You can also not mix and match libraries compiled with different compilers and once you start compiling from source, you have to compile all libraries from source (since the binary packages do not provide the development libraries that Windows needs. On osX or Linux, the binary packages can be used to compile another library/model).